# Actual Movie Haikus: I'm sorry, Father / I should not have run away / I will avenge you

Tags: movies, haiku

I think this should be pretty easy. Determine what movie each haiku references.

1

> I'm sorry,  Father
>   I should not have run away
>   I will avenge you

2

> Little and broken
>   I remember everyone
>   Join my family

3

> Hear my tragic tale
>   Love before the petal falls
>   Won't you please be mine

4

> Alone in the wild
>   Growing up to save us all
>   He will lead the band

5

> Strangers take her in
>   Each one unique but the same
>   The old hag's scheme fails

6

> Fighting for honor
>   Protecting my family
>   Though done with deceit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1

> The Lion King!

2

> Probably Lilo and Stitch. Thanks VictorHenry! Ohana means family!

3

> Beauty and the Beast

4

> This, Tarzan. You, Jane.

5

> Snow White and the Seven Dwarves

6

> Mulan! I'll make a man... out of YOOOOOOUUUUU!!

Comment: I think 2 is Lilo & Stitch and 4 is Tarzan.

Comment: @VictorHenry is correct on both counts. All of the others are right. That was about as fast as I expected, haha.

Comment: Not sure about Tarzan. If it were pack (as in pack of gorillas) and not band, it would fit better. Oh, nevermind then. lol

Comment: @Kingrames a band is actually the correct term for a group of gorillas

Comment: Shows what I know! Thanks for the correction!

Comment: Even in Haiku form the Lion King is a ripoff of _Hamlet_ :)

Answer (score 1):

W.I.P.

5. > Snow White, taken in by 7 dwarves, each of which has a different name based on an attribute. An evil witch attempts to put her in an eternal coma but she's awakened by true love's kiss.
6. > Mulan, who defends her family's honor fighting in her father's stead but pretending to be a man

Not sure if they are all

> Disney princesses or disney movies

or not